# Invoking sendto() with wrong length

Tags: c, linux, sendto

`ssize_t sendto(int socket, const void *message, size_t length, int flags, const struct sockaddr *dest_addr, socklen_t dest_len);`

In the above `sendto()` synopsis, 3rd field represents `length` which is ideally be the size of `message` being sent in bytes.

What if the `length` field is wrong and not equivalent to size of `message` ?

Will `sendto()` succeeds sending only length bytes mentioned. If yes, what happens if the length is bigger compared to real valid `message` size.

Comment: Nothing will go wrong! Because everything is right with UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sendto()` has no concept of the type of buffer you use for your messages.  It only knows about the parameter values you give it, so it is your responsibility to make sure they are accurate.

If the `length` is smaller than the actual message, `length` number of bytes are sent for UDP, and up to `length` bytes are sent for TCP.

If the `length` is larger than the actual message, the behavior is undefined.  At best, you will likely send random data from surrounding memory. At worse, you will crash your code when trying to send bytes from invalid memory.

Comment: Crashing is the best case here, as it is by far easier to find and fix than a random data corruption that affects a  remote site.